# How to send Excel as an attachment in email Using mandrill with Python 3.6.8

Tags: python, mandrill

Can anyone help on how to send an email with excel attachment using mandrill in python.
I am using python 3.6.8 version as my project is old version and has dependencies which do not allow me to upgrade the python version.
Here is the code I am using

```
 def _send_message(to, subject, htmlbody, add_header=True, cc=None, 
    bcc=None, attachment=None, attachment_content=None):
   if os.getenv('MGC_ENV') != 'prod':
       subject = '[{0}] '.format(os.getenv('MGC_ENV')) + subject

   if add_header:
       subject = 'MAP {0}'.format(subject)
    
    recipients = _generate_recipients(to, cc, bcc)

    if len(recipients) == 0:
       return

    bundle = {
       'to': recipients,
       'from_email': os.getenv('FROM_EMAIL'),
       'subject': subject,
       'html': htmlbody,
       'tags': _MANDRILL_TAGS,
       'preserve_recipients': True
     }

    if attachment and attachment_content:
        attachment = [{
          "type": 'application/xlsx',
          "name": 'OrderConfirmation.xlsx',
          "content": attachment_content.toString('base64')
        }]
        bundle["attachments"] = attachment

    if os.getenv('ENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS') == 'false':
       return

    _mandrill_client.messages.send(bundle)
```

The issue in the above code is the attachment is expecting the content as string encoded with base64 and when tried to set bytes array it wont work.

When we try to convert the excel into the type string it is not able to read and is breaking.

```
def export(licenses, plain_str=True): workbook = xlwt.Workbook()

    products_sheet = _create_product_sheet(workbook)

    product_row_offset = 1

    cell_style = xlwt.easyxf('font: underline single; font: color 
    blue')

    if licenses and len(licenses) > 0:
      for lic in licenses:
          row = products_sheet.row(product_row_offset)
          _write_product_row(row, lic, cell_style=cell_style)
          product_row_offset += 1

    if plain_str:

        content = utils.workbook_to_str(workbook)
     else:
        content = utils.workbook_to_bytes(workbook)
        return content



   def workbook_to_str(workbook):
       io_buffer = io.StringIO()
       workbook.save(io_buffer)

       return io_buffer.read()



   def workbook_to_bytes(workbook):
       io_buffer = io.BytesIO()
       workbook.save(io_buffer)

       return io_buffer.getvalue()
```

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added the code for better understanding.

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: I couldn't send the email with attachment using mandrill. And I have to use only Python 3.6.8 and mandrill in the project.

Comment: Explained the issue in detail in Question. Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Community Can anyone help Plz

Comment: @EDG956 Can you plz help

Comment: Yeah, but do you get an error, or it just doesn't arrive? do you see any errors in mandrill?

Comment: @EDG956 I could able to send the email with attachment but that attachment is not readable. I have used Data frame of pandas library to create excel sheet as mentioned in answer provided. It worked

Answer (score 3):

I'm no Python wizard (yet) but I've got the MailChimp integration working (pretty much the same as Mandril) using the below.

The parts that I struggled with were encoding the xlsx - `base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(df_xlsx).decode('UTF-8')` and finding the correct attachment type `'type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'`

```
import mailchimp_transactional as MailchimpTransactional
from mailchimp_transactional.api_client import ApiClientError
import base64
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

def send_email_notification():
    MANDRILL_API_KEY = Secret.load("mandrill-api-key")
    MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = MANDRILL_API_KEY.get()

    try:
        mailchimp = MailchimpTransactional.Client(MAILCHIMP_API_KEY)
        response = mailchimp.users.ping()
        print('API called successfully: {}'.format(response))
    except ApiClientError as error:
        print('An exception occurred: {}'.format(error.text))

    df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
                       index=['row 1', 'row 2'],
                       columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])

    def to_excel(df):
        output = BytesIO()
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        writer.save()
        processed_data = output.getvalue()
        return processed_data

    df_xlsx = to_excel(df)

    base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(df_xlsx).decode('UTF-8')



    message = {
        "from_email": "noreply@emailtest.com",
        "from_name": "Test",
        "subject": "The model has run successfully",
        'attachments': [{'name': 'test.xlsx',
                         'type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                         'content': base64_encoded
                         }],
        "to": [
            {
                "email": emailaddress,
                "name": "",
                "type": "to"
            }
        ]
    }


    try:
        mailchimp = MailchimpTransactional.Client(MAILCHIMP_API_KEY)
        response = mailchimp.messages.send({"message": message})
        print('API called successfully: {}'.format(response))
    except ApiClientError as error:
        print('An exception occurred: {}'.format(error.text))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_email_notification()
```

Comment: Used DataFrame to create Excel Sheet. It worked with mandrill too. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @BStrange cheers for this, small world eh :)